# SDL Image Not Supported : cute2.png is not a PNG file, or PNG support is not available

Tags: winapi, png, sdl

I was just trying a tutorial, as :

- http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson03/windows/msvsnet0508e/index.php
- http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson02/index.php

and tried to load and display my Portable Network Graphics (`.png`) files with in application as through simple code snippet:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
#include "SDL_mixer.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

//The attributes of the screen
const int screen_width = 640;
const int screen_height = 480;
const int screen_bpp = 32;              

//The surfaces that will be used
SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *message = NULL;

SDL_Surface *load_image( std::string filename ) 
{
    //The image that's loaded
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

    //The optimized image that will be used
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    SDL_RWops *rwop;
    rwop=SDL_RWFromFile(filename.c_str(), "rb");
    if(IMG_isPNG(rwop))
        printf("%s is a PNG file.\n", filename.c_str());
    else
        printf("%s is not a PNG file, or PNG support is not available.\n", filename.c_str());

    //Load the image using SDL_image
    loadedImage = IMG_Load( filename.c_str() );

    //If the image loaded
    if( loadedImage != NULL )
    {
        //Create an optimized image
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );

        //Free the old image
        SDL_FreeSurface( loadedImage );
    }

    //Return the optimized image
    return optimizedImage;
}


void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source_surface, SDL_Surface *destintion_Surface)
{
    //Make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
    SDL_Rect rectangle;

    //Give the offsets to the rectangle
    rectangle.x = x;
    rectangle.y = y;

    //Blit the surface
    SDL_BlitSurface(source_surface, NULL, destintion_Surface, &rectangle);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Initialize all SDL subsystems
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
        return 1;

    //Set up the screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(screen_width, screen_height, screen_bpp, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    //If there was an error in setting up the screen
    if(screen == NULL)
        return 1;

    //Set the window caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Surface Bliting", NULL);

    //Load the images
    background = load_image("cute2.png");
    message = load_image("cute4.png");

    //Apply the background to the screen
    apply_surface(0, 0, background, screen);
    apply_surface(320, 0, background, screen);
    apply_surface(0, 240, background, screen);              
    apply_surface(320, 240, background, screen);

    //Apply the message to the screen
     apply_surface( 180, 140, message, screen );    

    //Update the screen
    if(SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
        return 1;

    SDL_Delay(12000);

    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_FreeSurface(message);

    //Quit SDL
     SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Now within Visual Stdio 2008, the application is running quite nicely.

But when I am trying to run my `.exe` directly from my application:

```
E:\SDL_sample\SDL Image Extension Libraries\Release\"SDL Image Extension Libraries.exe"
```

the `stdout.txt` is showing messages:

> cute2.png is not a PNG file, or PNG support is not available.
>   cute4.png is not a PNG file, or PNG support is not available.

and the window closes without even displaying/rendering anything.

I don't understand how the images loading successfully when I **build/run** the application within Visual Studio 2008, but when I run the `.exe`, the images are not loading, where the **image files, dll and every thing is just same in their location**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `Working Directory` for your Solution isn't the same as your `Output Directory`. Your `\Release` folder is where your compiled executable is output and it doesn't seem to contain the `DLL` files `SDL_Image` is looking for to load support for PNG file format (probably `libpng##.dll`).

An easy fix would simply to copy all the dynamic link libraries you depend on to your `Output Directory`, whatever it is, so that when you launch the program, it finds all of them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer to what **emartel** have said you need to change the *Working Directory*. Go to your *Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working Directory*. Change the Working Directory similar to your *Output Directory* and copy all your media (e.g. images, sounds, .etc) files over there.

The reason why you can see the image on your app is because VS as default uses the project directory as a current working directory where I assumed you put your media / assets file. As an alternative you could set your working directory inside the code using WinAPI [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks **Fitz Abucay** for guidelines, It's really tough to get the default work flow of VS that it does default ... 

I didn't found any documentation regarding these all, so all as your experience we all need guidance ... :)